# EACCESS denied android pre-4.4

Tags: java, android, file

I am having trouble writing a file to `ENVIRONMENT.DOWNLOADS` on `API 16,17,18`.  I have the permission set in my manifest, and it works with `API 19+`, but denies access an `API < 19`.  I'm using `getExternalPublicStorage()`, and Dexter to manage permissions on newer devices, if that makes a difference.

Only things I've noticed is that the directory returned from that method call is different after `API 19`.

Has anyone else had a problem like this?  I'm at my witts end.

Here's the file constructor I'm using -

```
File csvFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName);
```

It fails when being passed to the CSV writer constructor here -

```
CSVWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

Any help or insight at all will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the directory exist?

Comment: ,`but denies access an API < 19`. Complete exact message please.

Comment: Can you share some logs for the relating issue?

Comment: Check to be sure that external storage is actually available by calling `Environment.getExternalStorageState()`.  External storage may be removable on some devices.

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in your App Manifest :-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```